# How do weather apps work?

Tags: ios7, weather

So I was thinking of making a weather app with a hidden twist but I'm not quite sure where to start. How does it work can you buy the data from a weather company if anyone knows any good tutorials it would also be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use something called a web service API. Google that.

Comment: voting to close: this is not a very focused programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are commercial services like [Weather Underground](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/?ref=twc), and free services like [National Weather Service](http://www.weather.gov). Look around at the options, read the terms of service and pricing, and pick one that suits your needs.